# image should be moved using mouse in a particular area

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

i took a uiview application.i placed a image on the controller's view.my requirement is the image should be movable  with the help of mouse.mouse should select the image and the image should be moved as the mouse is dragged.the image movement should be restricted to only a particular portion of the view.
 can someone help me  code the desirable task
tnx in advance

dinakar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with touchesBegan and touchesMoved events.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // This gets you starting position of 
    UITouch *touch = [ [ event allTouches ] anyObject ] ;   

    float touchXBeginPoint = [ touch locationInView:touch.view ].x ;
    float touchYBeginPoint = [ touch locationInView:touch.view ].y ;

    // Calculate the offset between the current image center and the touched points.
    //  Moving image only along X - direction and try thinking as how to move in 
    // any direction using this as a reference. It isn't that hard.

    touchOffset = image.center.x - touchXBeginPoint ;
    // touchOffset should be a member variable of class or a variable with global scope

} 

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Calculate the difference from previous position and the current position
    // Add this difference to the previous point and move the image center to that point.
    // How ever, you should have an UIImageView outlet connected on to the image placed
    // on the interface builder.

    // And regarding image movement restriction, since you always have co-ordinates with
    // you, you can set the boundaries.

    UITouch *touch = [ [ event allTouches ] anyObject ] ;

    float distanceMoved =( [ touch locationInView:touch.view ].x + touchOffset ) -  image.center.x  ;
    float newX = image.center.x + distanceMoved ;

    if( newX > 30 && newX < 290 ) // setting the boundaries
        image.center = CGPointMake(newX, image.center.y) ;
}
```

Hope this should be helpful.

Comment: hii mahesh tnx for the answer.the approach is same as i require.i tried by this code:                                                   [scale setFrame:CGRectMake(touchXBeginPoint+(touchLocation-touchXBeginPoint), touchYBeginPoint+(touchLocation-touchYBeginPoint), scaleFrame.size.width, scaleFrame.size.height)]; scale is the imageView.the error i get is 'touchXBeginPoint' undeclared.can u plz look into this.if u could not understand my code plz give a sample code according to my task.i will try using the code in my code accordingly.hope u would help me.

Comment: `the error i get is 'touchXBeginPoint' undeclared` - The error message is far clearer. How ever, posted the new code. Please go through the link given by Ishu.

Answer (score 3):

Dinakar i am very sorry to tell you that there is no mouse (cursor) in iphone or ipad.

Comment: What you need to do is create a UIScrollView in that place a image and than in .m file define its size (UIScrollView) and rest wil be taken care of

Comment: No there is no mouse pointer in any of the devices. Why will you need a mouse when the devices are touch sensitive.

Comment: i am sorry i didn't communicate correctly.i mean touch itself.mahesh has helped me in that regard.if u can plz u too try to post some code with the touch events according to my task.                          tnq and sorry once again

Comment: its ok, but you dont need to complicate your code code just just create a UIScrollView and then increase its size to your requirements and then on top it add an uiimageview and make it the size of the scroll view and then in .m file just specify the amount of area that the scrolview is covering. You dont need to do much in the code.

Answer (score 3):

robin is right.mouse cursor just use as a touch for simulator so these are not separate events

you need to read tutorials for moving images.see this [link](http://icodeblog.com/2009/02/18/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-2-user-interaction-simple-ai-game-logic/).

This will be help you.